# MapApply not converting numbers as strings to numbers

Tags: core-language

I have large vectors that were imported and came in as strings.  I try to convert these to numbers using MapApply of ToExpression (and the "@@@" form of this).  There must be some subtle problem with what I'm doing.  Suggestions?  I obviously have the test2 workaround.

```
aNumberSet = {"1.360", "1.237", "1.039", "1.490", "1.121"};
test1 = MapApply[ToExpression, aNumberSet];
test2 = ToExpression[#] & /@ aNumberSet;
test3 = ToExpression @@@ aNumberSet;
NumberQ[#] & /@ test1
NumberQ[#] & /@ test2
NumberQ[#] & /@ test3


(* Out[186]= {False, False, False, False, False} *)

(* Out[187]= {True, True, True, True, True} *)

(* Out[188]= {False, False, False, False, False} *)
```

Comment: `ToExpression /@ aNumberSet`

Comment: `MapApply` doesn't just apply the function in the normal sense of "apply a function to arguments" (that's what `Map` does), but combines `Map` with `Apply`, and `Apply` replaces the head of its argument. But then there's the special case where the argument is considered to be an atomic expression. Look at `anything @@ "1.360"`.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!  A little knowledge was dangerous.  I like your /@ solution.

Comment: `ToExpression@aNumberSet` would also work since `Attributes[ToExpression]` indicates that the function is `Listable`.